# NotSupportedException was unhandled (gridview C#)

Tags: c#, gridview, paging

I am trying to display my data in a gridview.
It works fine, until . . . . .
I want to do paging (20 data per page), it causes an error NotSupportedException was unhandled .

How do i solve this?

This is my code. 
I also have set paging to true.

```
public void bindGV()
    {
        string strCon = Database.GetConStr();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Account", sqlCon);
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        StaffGV.DataSource = reader;
        StaffGV.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GV.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGV();
    }
```

The error comes from the GV_PageIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the code from the `PageIndexChanging` event & see what happens.

Read your code again & it implies that - on every click of the next page, you would want to fetch the data from the database and bind it to the datagrid. This must **not** be done.

You don't need to do anything explicit to handle paging in datagrid, except to set a few properties. Read some intro tutorials on how to handle paging in datagrid.

Comment: Edit your own question & post the stacktrace of the exception.